# Replace zero in 2D array with blank space

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have a 2D array which has values in certain indices and has 0 in the other. How can I convert the 0 to a blank space. I tried `a[i][j] = ' '`,
but then it prints the ASCII value 32, I guess.

Comment: Print it as a character instead of an integer.

Comment: ... and pick ***a*** language.

Comment: I didnt get you @chris?
I use a for loop to print my matrix and was wondering if this conversion is possible inside it

Comment: you have C++ and C the answer for the question will be different depending on the language

Comment: When you say "it prints" - what prints what, and how?

Comment: show the declaration of a

Comment: Oh. I am using C++. PRinting out using cout

Comment: Do you want all of them to be characters or just the spaces, with integers everywhere else (which is a bit odd imo)?

Comment: int array[count][count]

Comment: Use [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace).

Comment: Just the 0 in my integer array should be a space

Comment: You can't store space in an integer array. a[i][j]=' ' is equivalent to a[i][j]=32

Comment: @user2803194 People here are confused; you could prevent it by posting code. You can do it even now (click on the "edit" link near your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i=0;i<r;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<c;j++)
        if (a[i][j]==' ')
            cout << (char)a[i][j];
        else
            cout << a[i][j];
```

Comment: OP wanted to replace 0 by space. This code prints a space instead of 32.

Comment: -1 This prints blank space instead of 32 which is some meaningful value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are printing the value of each occurence of the array and those too many 0 are hurting lisibility, so you prefer to display a ' ' instead of a 0.
No knowing much more of your development, I assume that best solution is to to it when you display the result:

```
if (a[i][j] == 0) {
  cout << ' ';
}
else {
 cout << a[i][j];
}
```

If using MVC, then your model must still be 0, but your view should display a space.